# not able to turn off archive_mode PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I am not able to turn off the archive mode. wal files are filling up so quickly in DEV environment

I have made symbolic link to another location for pg_wal file. still it is taking so much space

my postgesql.conf file looks like below

```
archive_mode = off
#archive_command = '/bin/true'
#archive_timeout = 0
wal_level = replica
#max_wal_sender =10
#wal_keep_size =0
```

but, if I check below query archive_mode is on

```
select name,setting from pg_settings where name like 'archive%' ;
name                           setting
archive_cleanup_command 
archive_command 
archive_mode                   on
archive_timeout                0
```

it is filling the space very quickly and stopping PostgreSQL server.

is there anything i need to to do stop archiving please advice me?, thank you

Comment: Did you stop and restart the PostgreSQL cluster after changing this setting? Because "off" means there will be no archiving, unless you didn't restart the server after the config change.

Comment: If restarting does not help add source, sourcefile to your pg_settings query to make sure that `archive_mode` is not being set from some source other then postgesql.conf.

Comment: thank you, restart helped me. I was always reloading conf file

Comment: pg_wall file started filling up again now it is 850 GB. with the above setting. I have stopped the the replication because of space issue. is this causing any issue. please help. thank you.